# comma inside if statment in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've searched in SO but I didn't find something similar. Maybe I am using wrong search keys.
I was editing a javascript library when I found this `if` statment

```
    var a = location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");

    if (container = $("#content"), a) {
       ..content
    } else {
        ...other code
    }
```

the first part `container = $("#content")` is assigning the value of  `$("#content")` to container but I don't understand why there is a comma inside the If. Is it like an `AND` operator?
Something like  `if (container = $("#content") && a)` ?
What is it evaluating?

Comment: Javascript is (so far) my main programming language. I've seen that operator before, but only when it's *actually* useful. In this case, it seems like that just wanted to 'save a line' by throwing the assignment in the `if` statement. In my opinion, that's not very readable. Though I suppose that if this is library code that 'every byte counts', but even then the library can/should be minified. So why they wrote the code this way... definitely a mystery to me.

Comment: thanks @ChrisCirefice, I will keep this in consideration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator in JavaScript is pretty similar to the concept in other C-like languages. It's a way of stringing multiple expressions together into one (syntactic) expression. The value of the whole thing is the value of the last expression in the list.

Thus in this case, `container = $("#content")` is evaluated, and then `a` is evaluated. The value of the whole thing is the value of `a`.

A good question is *why* that code was written that way. There are times when the comma operator is useful, but usually it's just a way to save some typing and make code a little more concise.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know it

Answer (score 2):

It is comma operator.

Basically its doing two things. First there is assignment and then the `,` just evaluates `a` and validates against it in the `if` condition.

Comment: thanks! never stop learning